# How can I enable template 10 in Visual Studio community 2017 RC?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, template10, visual-studio-community

If I download from https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki
and open the template 10 solution in Visual Studio Community 2017 RC, it does not work.
Is it complicated to make it work easily or shall I download vs 2015?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for improving Template10? or Using Template10 in your solution? If you want to use Template10, Use tools --> Extensions & Updates and search for Template 10. You will see Template10 Templates moving forward when you create new projects.

Comment: It has not be released in VS17 RC form.  It requires a second VSIX to be created for it to be usable but then that doubles the complexity.  Supposedly VS2017 will eventually work with all packages back to 2012 from what I have read

Comment: I am new to UWP and I try to find examples to train. Template 10 seems to be adequate for this?

Comment: On VS17 RC, if I create a new blank solution, "template 10" is not displayed when using "Tools > Extensions & Updates" and searching for "Template 10". Did you try to migrate your VSIX automatically, if it is possible? If it is so complicated to migrate at every new version of VS, it is not very encouraging to use templates and nugets in my UWP projects, isn't it?

Comment: I am from France, that explains my answer time difference.

Comment: I have just tried on VS Express 2015 for Windows 10: "Tools > Extensions and updates > Online", searching "Template10" => "No items found". Do I miss something? Does it work on this version of VS 2015?

Comment: As an information, my OS version is Windows 10 Entreprise 2016 LTSB. I do not know if that is important? (I started with 2015 LTSB version and VS 2015 did not work until I migrate).

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no Template 10 extension for Visual Studio 2017, only Visual Studio 2015. As a short-term work around until the Visual Studio 2017 extension is released, you can create your project in Visual Studio 2015 using the Template 10 extension and then open it in Visual Studio 2017 to develop it. There will likely be no Template 10 extension for Visual Studio 2017 until it is RTM. As of this moment, Visual Studio 2017 is Release Candidate version 5 and it is wonderful. I can assure you, since I am the author of Template 10, that Visual Studio 2017 will be fully supported @ RTM. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-2017-rc/

Comment: So sad, still no template available

Answer (score 1):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerry-nixon.Template10TemplatePack

VS2015 should be just fine... VS2017RC will not work....

Comment: I 've just tried and failed. The log says this is available only for: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community, Pro and Enterprise, Version : [14.0] (=2015). As I have only installed VS 2015 Express for Windows 10 and VS Community 2017 RC, that failed. That's a pity that Express does not work, is there a technical reason for this?

Comment: I 've just installed my third version of VS... VS Community 2015. The install of "Template 10" using your link succeeded. Thanks.

Comment: I 've just made the following experiment: 1/ I've created using VSC 2015 an new Hamburger (Template 10) project, and run it, then closed VS. 2/ I've opened the project on VS 2017 RC, and run it: that's succeeded! The only missing thing is that, on VS 2017, if you create a new project you will not have the Template10 templates displayed as a choice.

Comment: I've tried opening this project with "VS Express 2015 for Windows 10" and running it: that's succeeded too! No template10 template displayed neither.

Comment: Community Edition and above CE is basically Pro without the price.  Express doesn't allow extensions...